# Help me remember this book from the 90's

Tags: story-identification

I have been trying to remember these FOR YEARS with no luck. I read these no later than the mid to late 90's though I don't know if they were new/old at the time. I have only vague memories of plot and characters apart from remembering they were enjoyable. I think there were at least two books, but it could have been 1.

The only specific detail I remember that might be unique is of an elite group of troops that had been magically castrated, leaving testicles to promote aggression but only a small nub instead of a penis, and each troop was given a straw (gold maybe?) to use to pee through with the nub.

I think a villain may have been termed an Archon, or maybe that was in the title? I don't know and could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! I spent a few hours looking through lists of fantasy authors & books from the 80's & 90s, using google books and amazon "search inside" for any that seemed at all familiar.

The Far Kingdom series by Allan Cole &  Chris Bunch struck a very familiar chord, and I found my answer in the second book, The Warrior's Tale. The group of castrated soldiers were called The Sarzana's Own.

Comment: “The group of castrated soldiers were called The Sarzana's Own.” I *think* you’ll find they’re called *The Unsullied*.

Comment: Hah, yes. But while I won't debate the relative merits of the the double-R over AC & CB, this book of theirs preceded his. Though it's not as though castrated servants of any sort are unique in fact or fiction.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly ["The Wasp Factory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wasp_Factory) written in 1984 by Ian Banks. Stars a transexual protagonist (sort of; she thinks she's a man who had her penis bitten off by a dog as a boy) with a father named Angus (possibly confused with Archon?) who is a bit of a piece of work (he lies about the dog thing and has been pumping her full of testosterone since childhood to see what would happen).

I haven't read the book, this is really just based on some google-fu. Sorry, but more details would potentially be a big help.

Comment: No, it was definitely fantasy, and the castrated were a group a troops not an individual.